# Shiny Table app with money in one column and filer by factor?

Tags: shiny

I'm trying to create a shiny app that is basically a table, with an about tab.

There are two things I'm having troubles with:

1. One of the columns is has a dollar amount. I would like the formatting to be $1,225. The closest I can get to that is to use paste0, but when you sort the column it does not work as expected and i don't get the comma for thousands.
2. I would like to be able to a a drop down menu with the option "All, A, C, D". If I choose "A" it will show me the table only for "Something==A". Right now this is working, but I'm not sure if I coded in the best possible way.

This is my ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  title = 'Some tittle',
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput('show_vars', 'Columns to show:',
                         c("Something", "Money"), 
                         selected = c("Money")),
      selectInput(inputId = "Something",
                  label = "Choose a category",
                  choices = c("All", "A", "C", "D"),
                  selected = "All")
      ),

    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id = 'dataset',
        tabPanel('Table', dataTableOutput('mytable1')),
        tabPanel('about', includeMarkdown("about.md"))
      )
    )
  )
))
```

my server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
DF1 = data.frame("Rank"=1:4, "Something"=as.factor(c("A","A","C","D")), "Money"=c(2345.5, 1234.67, 5.2, 9878.46))
# change the data to have dollar sign
DF1 = DF1 %>% mutate(Money= paste0("$",round(Money,0))) 
original = DF1
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  observe({
    if(input$Something!="All"){
      DF1 = original %>% filter(Something==input$Something)
      # a large table, reative to input$show_vars
      output$mytable1 <- renderDataTable({
        DF1[, c("Rank", input$show_vars), drop = FALSE]
      })
      }else{
      DF1 = original
      output$mytable1 <- renderDataTable({
        DF1[, c("Rank", input$show_vars), drop = FALSE]
      })
      }
})
})
```

and my about.md

```
# Title
+ bla
+ bla
+ bla
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: See `scales::dollar()` for dollar formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution, but I'm sure this code could be better. If someone can give me advice on how to improve it, I would appreciate it :-). My solution is to use scales to add the comma

My server looks like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
DF1 = data.frame("Rank"=1:4, "Something"=as.factor(c("A","A","C","D")), "Money"=c(2345.5, 1234.67, 5.2, 9878.46))
# change the data to have dollar sign
DF1 = DF1 %>% mutate(Money=round(Money,0)) %>% mutate(Money=comma_format()(Money)) %>% mutate(Money=paste0("$",Money))
original = DF1
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  observe({
    if(input$Something!="All"){
      DF1 = original %>% filter(Something==input$Something)
      # a large table, reative to input$show_vars
      output$mytable1 <- renderDataTable({
        DF1[, c("Rank", input$show_vars), drop = FALSE]
      })
      }else{
      DF1 = original
      output$mytable1 <- renderDataTable({
        DF1[, c("Rank", input$show_vars), drop = FALSE]
      })
      }
})
})
```

I think the reactive part is very inefficient, but I'm not sure how to improve that yet.